# What is the meaning of css property preceded with --

Tags: css, sass, less

I found this CSS property in a webpage template. It is styled inline and I have found it, not only in one template. Then I searched google and was not able to get the right answer.
So, my question is: What does it mean to precede a CSS property with `--` when styling inline.

The one i found is `--logo-color: rgba(238,238,238,1);`

Comment: Take a look at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

Comment: TLDR its a variable that can be referenced later using color: var(--logo-color);

Comment: Thank @Branson Smith